# How to upload encrypted data to Amazon S3 using AmazonS3EncryptionClient?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload encrypted data to Amazon S3. I found that it's supported feature in latest [AWS SDK for .net](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html) but all their [examples are in JAVA](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryptionUpload.html). Anyone has ever uploaded encrypted data to S3 (Client-Side encryption) using C# code? I can encrypt use Server-Side encrypt feature but cant figure out how to do client side encryption.

I am looking for example how to use AmazonS3EncryptionClient and EncryptionMaterials class from AWS SDK.

Comment: Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/TxL15A0QZMD38D/-Client-Side-Data-span-class-matches-Encryption-span-with-AWS-SDK-for-NET-and-Am)

Comment: Thank you for this link... This is exactly what I was looking for.